# Relationship between Inner and Outer Class in Java?

Tags: java, class, javap

This is my Book.java code

```
public class Book {
    private int pageNumber;

    private class BookReader{
        public int getPage(){
            return pageNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

When I complied it and used `javap` I got following things for the two classes

For `Book$BookReader.class`

This is the output code

```
Compiled from "Book.jav
class Book$BookReader {
  final Book this$0;
  public int getPage();
}
```

My question is why **final** is added while making any reference here and why this reference was made? What is its use in innerclass?

For `Book.class`

```
$ javap Book.class
Compiled from "Book.java"
public class Book {
  public Book();
  static int access$000(Book);
}
```

Why static is added for variable and why Book has been passed as parameter here?

Please explain it in simple terms if possible!

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/a/28462949/1393766

Comment: Got the first part. Thanks a lot 
 can you explain about second part why static has been added for variable ?

Comment: http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/07/java-secret-generated-methods.html I didn't read this article entirely but it seems promising.

Comment: Also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199175/java-inner-outer-class-questions-about-outer-class-private-variables-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `BookReader`, the `final` variable `this$0` will hold a reference to the `BookReader`'s containing `Book` instance.  This is `final` because it is determined for each `BookReader` instance when that instance is created, by the manner of its creation, and cannot thereafter change.

In class `Book`, the static method `access$000` is a synthetic accessor method for the benefit of class `Book.BookReader`.  As an inner class of `Book`, each `BookReader` has access to the member variables of its containing instance, but the Java runtime does not actually know this, and the class file format has no special representation for it.

For `BookReader` to be able to access *`private`* member `Book.pageNumber`, therefore, the compiler generates a synthetic, default-access method for that purpose in class `Book`, and in `BookReader` writes accesses to the outer class's variable in terms of that method.

Answer (score 0):

A non static inner class has a reference to its parent instance. That is the

```
final Book this$0;
```

The reference to the parent Book instance cannot be changed at run time, which is why it is final. Which is to say your BookReader has a reference to exactly on Book that is assigned on construction and cannot be changed later.

The line:

```
static int access$000(Book);
```

Is a package-level static accessor method. It is used to allow the inner class access the private members of the outer.

Answer (score 0):

You define `BookReader` by:

```
class Book {
    private class BookReader {  }
}
```

This class relies on an instance of `Book` being created therefore the compiler creates the reference and makes it final (this is an optimisation as each `Book` instance can create `BookReader`)

If you defined `BookReader` by:

```
class Book {
    private static class BookReader {  }
}
```

Then the reference would not exist as a Book reader can be created without an instance of Book.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class).